# C# Interface implemented by empty abstract class

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

Can I leave an abstract class that implements interfaces empty and imply that all the methods/properties in the interface are abstract within my class. It appears that I have to write them out again in the abstract class but I really want to avoid this duplication.

My reason is I have a couple of interfaces with different accessors, one public and one internal, that I want to bring together so I have an abstract class that implements them both that can then be extended.

```
public interface ISomePublicProperties {
    int PropertyOne {get;}
}

internal interface ISomeInternalProperties {
    int PropertyTwo {get;}
}

public abstract class SomeClass : ISomePublicProperties, ISomeInternalProperties {}
```

But the compiler complains that SomeClass does not implement interface method ISomePublicProperties.PropertyOne and ISomeInternalProperties.PropertyTwo

Is there anyway in C# (I know Java allows this) that I can leave the abstract class empty implementing interfaces?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a `virtual` stub method to shut the compiler up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope. In C# the abstract class must fully implement the interface. Note it *can* implement it with abstract methods and abstract properties. It's one little thing about C# that has always bugged me.

Comment: While you can implement with abstract properties, it seems you can't implement *explicitly* with abstract properties. The following complains that abstract members cannot be private -- "abstract int ISomePublicProperties.PropertyOne { get; }". Unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do it is create `virtual` properties with no implementation.  These are then overridden in your derived classes.

```
public abstract class SomeClass : ISomePublicProperties, ISomeInternalProperties 
{
    public abstract int PropertyOne { get; }
    internal abstract int PropertyTwo { get; }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to avoid to have something like `public abstract int Property { get; }`

Comment: Thanks for the responses but I really wanted to avoid the duplication of the interfaces into the abstract class - I just wanted the abstract class to be empty and the extenders of the class to implement the interfaces.

Comment: This doesn't work because a virtual property must still have an implementation. You can add setters to them to make them auto properties (depends on the situation if that is a good idea or not), or make them abstract. Making them abstract is the closest thing possible to what the OP wants. Java handles this better than C# :)